# XSL - How to tell if element is last in series

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL template that is selected for execution (below).  What I would like to do is be able to tell if I am the last `Unit` being matched.

```
  <xsl:template match="Unit[@DeviceType = 'Node']">
    <!-- Am I the last Unit in this section of xml? -->
    <div class="unitchild">
      Node: #<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

Example XML

```
<Unit DeviceType="QueueMonitor" Master="1" Status="alive" id="7">
    <arbitarytags />
    <Unit DeviceType="Node" Master="0" Status="alive" id="8"/>
    <Unit DeviceType="Node" Master="0" Status="alive" id="88"/>
</Unit>
```

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for the only correct solution until now. See my comments to the currently selected answer to understand why it is not correct. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to test whether it is the last Unit element at the same level (with the same parent element), even if there are arbitrary tags before, after, and in-between then this would work:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Unit)">
```

However, if you are applying templates for a subset, the last in the document may not be in the set being processed. For that, you can test if the `position() = last()`

```
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
```

Comment: Will not work with any XML document and any `<xsl:apply-templates>` !

Comment: The original question is about the last Unit being matched, not the last sibling! Which is the last Unit being matched depends only on the expression in the `select` attribute of `<xsl:apply-templates>`, not on the phisical properties of the XML document.

Comment: @Dimitre: It also depends on the sort order applied (if any), not only the expression in the `select` attribute.

Answer (score 38):

**The currently selected answer is generally incorrect!**

> ```
> <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Unit)">
> ```

This Will not work with any XML document and any `<xsl:apply-templates>`

The original question is about the last `Unit` being matched, not the last sibling! Which is the last Unit being matched depends only on the expression in the select attribute of `<xsl:apply-templates>`, not on the physical properties of the XML document.

**The way to do it**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="SomeExpression"/>
```

**then in the template that matches nodes selected by `SomeExpression`:**

```
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
. . . . 
</xsl:if>
```

**This checks if the current node is the last in the `node-list` selected by `<xsl:apply-templates>`, not that the current node is the last sibling**. This answers exactly the original question.

If the question was framed in a different way, asking how to recognize if the last sibling `Unit` is the current node, then the best solution would be to specify a separate template for this last sibling node:

```
<xsl:template match="Unit[last()]">
    . . . . 
</xsl:template>
```

**Do note**, that in this case there is no need to write any conditional logic inside a template to test if the current node is "the last".

Answer (score 6):

### You should test position() = last(), but you should test it in predicate, not in the body of the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<data>
    <item group="B">AAA</item>
    <item>BBB</item>
    <item group="B">CCC</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item group="B">EEE</item>
    <item>FFF</item>
</data>
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@group]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    ITEM
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
    LAST IN CONTEXT
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[position() = last()]">
    LAST ITEM
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can test `position()` against `last()`:

```
<xsl:template match="Unit[@DeviceType = 'Node']">
 <!-- Am I the last Unit in this section of xml? -->     
 <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
   <!-- Yes I am! -->
   Last Unit
 </xsl:if>

 <div class="unitchild">
  Node: #<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
 </div>
</xsl:template>
```

See w3schools article on [`xsl:if`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_if.asp).

Comment: I tried looking at `position()`, however it also takes into account other nodes i.e. `<arbitarytags />` as opposed to just `Unit`

Comment: @Chris - it should only use the nodes that are in the template scope. You can try `./position()` and see if that helps.

Comment: your original @test condition(without `./`) produces the desired output for the sample, but `position()` and `last()` are 2:3 and 3:3 respectively for those Unit elements.  It isn't evaluating `position()` and `last()` in terms of the template match context(nodeset), but in terms of document order and position as children of the parent.

Comment: @Mads: This is incorrect. `position()` and `last()` inside a template consider the current context node list, not the document order. Whether or not the expression `position() = last()` will yield the intended result depends on the node set and sort order selected by the invoking `<xsl:apply-templates>`.  Note that if the normal identity transform is used - i.e. `select="node()|@*"` - the test will fail with the sample input provided, as the last node in the node set will not be a `Unit` element, but rather a text node representing the newline and indentation following the last `Unit` element.